# once made an ajax call, would there be a way to delete the data retrieved after use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make ajax calls every minute in my platform, necessary because the information changes every minute for n elements. However after 400 calls my platform copmmence to crash so I would like to know, once made an ajax call, would there be a way to delete the data retrieved after use?
or if you have other solutions.
cordially.

```
function updateMarker() {
for (i = 0; i < ArrMarker.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax-RT.php?IMEI=" + imeis[i],
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(params) {
            crudMarker(params);
        }
    });

    loading(i);
    evennements()
}
$(".valueLoad").text("100%");
$(".fullsize-loading").hide();
}

 window.setInterval(updateMarker, 60000);
```

Comment: you can maybe think about using web-sockets instead of an ajax call every 60 second

Comment: Not sure why it would crash, how are you storing the data? We need more info here to help.

Comment: There is always better way, but none can give you the answer because we don't know the situation. Example code could help

Comment: If you remove all references to a variable, the browser should remove unnecessary data when it's garbage collector runs.  Make sure you are not holding on the variable references past the point you no longer need them.

Comment: @MohammedBathily please put that in your question, formatted, and not in the comments so it is easier to read.